# How to avoid .dlls being replaced? (dotnet core assembly signing)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dll, .net-assembly

We have an **interface** (IPayment) that abstracts away different **provider implementations** (Paypal, CreditCard, Wire, Cash, Mock).

We want to ship these providers in one .dll, because this allows us to activate the right provider implementation based on the deployment environment (DEV, TEST, STAGE, PROD).

**We want to deliver to the customer a .dll that contains only a fixed provider implementation which the customer cannot change by replacing it with a different .dll.**

Is there a way to guarantee that the **dotnet core** application only runs using a specific set of .dlls that we have defined?

Comment: that's why you'd sign your assemblies: this guaranetees the assemblies you load are the assemblies you provided. So is this question about how to achieve signing?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain yes - I would like to find some resources (links) on how to do that and that the application does not start if the .dll is replaced (maybe a callback function is entered where I can print out a log message)

Comment: https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/challenge-response-system